# When is the gradient orthogonal to a surface?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis

The gradient is supposed to point in the direction of steepest ascent. But it is also said that the gradient of a function $f(x,y,z)$ is orthogonal to the level surfaces of $f$, i.e. the surfaces defined by $f(x,y,z)=k$. I'm having trouble using this fact in practice.

As an example, we can consider the surface $f(x,y,z)=w=x^2 + \ln(y) + z$

What does $\nabla f= [2x, \frac1y, 1]$ represent? I'm not sure how we can check whether this vector is tangent or orthogonal to the surface, because to do that I would need either a tangent or an orthogonal vector of the surface, which is what I'm trying to get in the first place.

And a level surface of $f$ would be $x^2+\ln(y) + z = 10$, but I'm not sure what to do with this equation.

Or maybe the relevant equation to look at would be $x^2 + \ln(y) + z - w = 0$, because then we could think of $f(x,y,z)$ as the level surface of the function $g(x,y,z,w) = x^2 + \ln(y) + z - w$ and its gradient $\nabla g = [\nabla f; -1]$?

Comment: Define $F(x,y,z)=x^2+\ln{y}+z$. Then your equation becomes a level surface for $F$ and $\nabla F$ will be perpendicular to your surface.

Comment: @JohnDouma Sorry, which equation? $f(x,y,z)=x^2 + \ln y + z$ was the original function I gave and is the same as the $F$ you defined. $F$ is a level surface of the function $g(x,y,z,w) = x^2 + \ln y + z - w$ (namely the curve we get when $g=0$), so does that mean $[2x, \frac1y, 1, -1]$ is perpendicular to $F$? How can we confirm this (which dot product should we expect to be 0)?

Comment: I recommend you look at one variable fewer and understand the difference between level *curves* of $f(x,y)$ in the $xy$-plane and the *graph* $z=f(x,y)$ in $xyz$-space. The direction of steepest ascent will be a vector in the $xy$-plane, telling you what direction to move so that $z$ increases at the greatest rate on the graph.

Comment: If you have a level curve $f=k$ then you can take the directional derivative in any direction which gives you $\nabla f(x,y,z)\cdot\hat u=0$ where $\hat u$ represents any direction. This is only possible if either the gradient is zero or the gradient is perpendicular to each direction vector which is equivalent to being perpendicular to the surface.

Comment: @TedShifrin Fair enough, so let us consider the surface $a=h(x,y)$ where $a$ is a variable, which has level curves $k=h(x,y)$ where k is a constant. Also, $a=h(x,y)$ can be rewritten as $0=h(x,y)-a$, which is a level surface of a hypersurface in $4$-space with equation $b(x,y,a)=h(x,y)-a$. My confusion arises because there are three possible gradients to calculate: the gradient of the surface itself, the gradient of a level curve of the surface, and the gradient of the hypersurface which the original surface is a level surface of. Which gradient should be used?

Comment: We compute gradients of functions, not of sets or surfaces. I don't know why you're put things in 4-space. That's just beyond confusing. The question is: What precise question are you trying to answer? The *normal* vector to the graph $z=f(x,y)$ is the gradient of the function $F(x,y,z)=f(x,y)-z$, as the graph $z=f(x,y)$ is the level set $F=0$.

Comment: But isn't $F(x,y,z)=f(x,y)-z$ a hypersurface in 4-space? And in general is it correct to say that if we want the normal vector to a function of $n$ variables (a graph in $n+1$-space), we need to calculate the gradient of a function with $n+1$ variables (a graph in $n+2$-space which has the first graph as a level set)?

Comment: No, $F(x,y,z)$ is a function. Its level surfaces are surfaces in 3-space. Yes, its graph is a hypersurface in 4-space. I keep telling you that you have to decide what is actually under discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose I have the surface $S$ defined by $f(x,y,z) = k$, and I draw a path parameterized as $\mathbf{x}(t) = (x(t), y(t),z(t))$ that is entirely within that surface. Since the path is in the surface, we will have $f(x(t), y(t),z(t)) = k$ for all $t$, and taking the $t$ derivative of both sides gives $\partial_t\mathbf{x} \cdot\nabla f = 0$. Now, $\partial_t\mathbf{x}$ is the velocity along the path, and in particular it is tangent to S (if it weren't, the path would leave S). Therefore, at all points of the path, $\nabla f$ is perpendicular to the surface tangent of $S$ along the path. But since the path chosen was arbitrary, that means $\nabla f$ is perpendicular to all surface tangents of $S$, and thus it is normal to $S$ at all points.

Comment: Thank you. Why can we take it for granted that $\partial f = \partial \mathbf{x}$? Intuitively it is clear that this is true, but $f$ and $\mathbf{x}$ are mathematically different objects (a function vs a curve parameterized with time) so it feels nontrivial to say that their rates of change are equal